# Why are linear discriminant analysis in SPSS and Python not giving me the same results for coefficients?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, spss, linear-discriminant

Although the data I'm feeding into both SPSS and Python is identical, I'm getting different scores for eigenvalues and canonical discriminant function coefficients while tests of equality of group means work accurately. Could you please offer a solution? I'm sharing the canonical discriminant function coefficients I got, SPSS syntax I ran and Python code I used below.

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
DISCRIMINANT
  /GROUPS=Gender(0 1)
  /VARIABLES=Height Width Div_Depth
  /ANALYSIS ALL
  /SAVE=CLASS PROBS 
  /PRIORS EQUAL 
  /STATISTICS=MEAN STDDEV UNIVF BOXM COEFF RAW CORR TABLE CROSSVALID 
  /CLASSIFY=NONMISSING POOLED.
```

SPSS Output:

- Height 8.376
- Width -.564
- Div_Depth -6.201
- (Constant) -29.031

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
X = data[["Height", "Width", "Div_Depth"]]
y = data["Gender"]
lda = LDA()
lda_model = lda.fit(X, y)
print("Canonical Discriminant Function Coefficients:", lda.coef_)
print("Canonical Discriminant Function Constant:", lda.intercept_)
```

Python Output:

- Canonical Discriminant Function Coefficients: `[[-101.85246698    6.86029024   75.4023029 ]]`
- Canonical Discriminant Function Constant: `[353.00578148]`

You can find the data sample I've used at https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d8e2252cf4878dad9ec2b5dea54d45d620230926202231/f8564eb573c9e4b5e2f70da3b2d909a920230926202259/8e586b?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show their respective outputs as copy-pasted text (with code fences to maintain monospacing) instead of creating a bullet list with paraphrased values. Also, there is a bit of work to do on your end in terms of forming a [mcve]: reduce your data to a toy problem with only as few entries, and as few axes per entry, as necessary to show off a difference in results. And then include that test data in your post, too. Not just so folks here have something they can reproduce, but because the MCVE exercise forces _you_ to perform an important problem analysis step.